# Issue:While retrieving the text field value from UITableView.

Tags: swift, uitableview

While retrieving the text field value from UITableView. I am getting empty value.But the Screen displays the value.

```
while counter <= sectionRowCount {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row:counter, section: 1)
            let itemcell:StoreDisplayCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! StoreDisplayCell
            print("ListItem = \(itemcell.item.text!)")
            print("Qty = \(itemcell.qty.text!)")
            print("des =  \(itemcell.item.description)")

      counter = counter + 1
```

}

My output is

```
ListItem = 
Qty =
```

Please provide input on this.

Comment: Using `dequeueReusableCell` gets you either a new cell or one from cache.  It's not a way to look at the currently displaying cells.  (What is the context for what you're trying to do?)

Comment: Fetch the value from the currently displaying cell

Comment: When I tried to use the below line           
   let itemcell:StoreDisplayCell =  tableView.cellForRow(at:indexPath) as! StoreDisplayCell.                                                                                             I am getting error.                                                                                                          Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have used let itemcell:StoreDisplayCell = tableView.cellForRow(at:indexPath). I able to fetch the value